# Sails JS + Angular JS : The routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I'm currently learning SailsJS, and I'm Angular's user. I understand that Angular can work with SailsJs without problem (Sails is back, Angular is front) and it works with success on my app.

On the other hand, I'm not sure with the routing : The Angular's router have to render the only views and Sails' router have to render API REST routes ? Or all routes are generated by Angular or Sails ?

I work with this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-todo-app-using-sailsjs-and-angularjs) but I'm embarrassed that Angular handles all the routing.

Regards,

Comment: Angular Router by default uses the hashtag (#) in the url for routing information. Everything behind this hashtag is never seen by the sails server and is only available at the clients browser. There is no real HTTP Request made for routing on the client side.  The Hashtag is described within the HTTP RFC. May that helps to clear up your mind.

Comment: yes, your comment is helpful, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just think of them as 2 seperate projects. Angular will handle all the frontend routing whereas sails will handle all the api routing. for example in angular you could make something like (using ui router, same would be true for using angular's standard routing)

```
.state('user-detail', {
  url: '/users/:id',
  views: {
    'content@': {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/view.html',
    controller: 'yourCtrl'
  }
}
})
```

and in sails you could load the user (triggered from `yourCtrl` in angular) through the route `/user/:id` (or something like `/api/users/:id` depending on your sails configuration).

In your example sails is taken care of the routing on the backend side - `http://localhost:1337/todo/addTodo` triggers the `todoController:addTodo()`

Comment: Oh ok ! I didn't understand that Blueprint generated the routes automatically, it's amazing ! I understand better the separation of the front and back. thank you it's ok now
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?restful-routes